# Delphi - how to enum string to type

Tags: delphi

I got strings in database like 'TGroupBox' or 'TEdit' ... now I need to check element against them... how do I enumerate string to type?

I mean something like this:

```
mystr := 'TGroupBox';
If (page.Controls[0] is mystr) then ...
```

Of course it won't work, as error appears:

> E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

How do I do that correctly?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am actually trying to do what I asked. To be able to use `is` operator on `string`. So I guess the best method would be to convert that `string` to `class`... but have no idea how.

Comment: You cannot use is with a string so if that's what you want to do, give up

Comment: You clearly cannot do that, because that's not what the `is` operator is for. Just because you want to use a hammer to try to cut glass to repair a broken window doesn't mean you can do so. If you'd answer my question and *explain what you're trying to accomplish*, there might be a way to do so.

Comment: Is this really such a bad question? The way I read it, the OP would like to use the `is` keyword, but knows she cannot since she doesn't have a class, but a string with a class name.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - indeed.

Comment: Why? What would you change? I really don't understand why isn't my question clear... I'm mentioning about casting string to type at least 2 times (once in question title)...

Comment: @Flash you said that you want *to be able to use is operator on string*.

Comment: @FlashThunder - your question as stated is just wrong, as David and Ken have explained:`is` checks for a **type**, `mystr` is **value**. Pay attention the error you are getting: _Operator not applicable to this operand type_ - that's what it means.

Comment: @Vector The use of "is" isn't wrong. It's the lack of ability to cast the string to a type that's the problem.

Comment: @alcalde - ???? mystr is a value - you cannot 'cast a value to a type' - that doesn't make any sense. What you can do is determine the `type name` that the string value corresponds to - UweRaabe's answer explains how to do that with RTTI.

Answer (score 4):

You can verify that

```
page.Controls[0].ClassName = mystr
```

using the [`ClassName`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.ClassName) property.

But notice that this doesn't do exactly the same thing as the `is` operator. To see the difference, suppose you have a class `TFruit` and a subclass `TApple`. If `myFruit` is an instance of a `TApple`, then both `myFruit is TApple` and `myFruit is TFruit` will yield `true`. But of course, the `ClassName` will still only be `TApple`.

If you need the full functionality of the `is` operator, you can make use of the [`ClassParent`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.ClassParent) property, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583120/delphi-how-to-enum-string-to-type#comment36194431_23583146) by hvd:

```
function IsDerivedFrom(AClass: TClass; const AClassName: string): boolean;
begin
  if not Assigned(AClass) then Exit(false);
  result := SameText(AClass.ClassName, AClassName) or
    IsDerivedFrom(AClass.ClassParent, AClassName);
end;
```

To get the class of an object, use the [`ClassType`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.ClassType) property:

```
IsDerivedFrom(page.Controls[0].ClassType, mystr);
```

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing as `is`. `page.Controls[0] is TControl` would evaluate as true, but `page.Controls[0].ClassName = 'TControl'` would evaluate as false.

Comment: @FlashThunder It only evaluates as true if you've got an exact match. `is` also returns true if the object you've got is derived from the type you're checking for.

Comment: Ah nvm... it works fine. I didn't understand your comment, but now I get it... exact match is fine. But still more `is` way would be great if anybody has an idea how to do that...

Comment: @FlashThunder Yes, in that case, a simple string comparison will do, but to answer your question anyway, if you do need to check base types too, you could write a recursive function `IsDerivedFrom(c: TClass; const name: string)`, which first checks for an exact match, and if it fails, calls `IsDerivedFrom(c.ClassParent, name)`. You could call it like `IsDerivedFrom(obj.ClassType, mystr)`. I'll let Andreas put it in this answer (if desired), or I can post it as a separate answer later.

Comment: @hvd No way to simply enum the string to class?

Comment: @FlashThunder No, that requires type registration, and even though Delphi does provide facilities for this (`RegisterClass` etc.), most types you find won't have been registered.

Comment: And how about `FindClass` ? Weird ... it returns `'TGroupBox' not found.`

Comment: @FlashThunder That's part of the "etc." :) It requires the type to have been registered first.

Comment: @hvd oh ok... really strange... but whatever :) I guess I'll use `ClassName` then...

Comment: The revised answer should use `SameText` instead of `SameStr` since the latter is case sensitive where the language (and so an `is` call) is not.

Comment: @Chris: The reason I used `SameStr` instead of `=` was that I wanted the case-insensitivity! I meant to use `SameText`!

Answer (score 3):

The function you are looking for is `GetClass` located in System.Classes. Be aware that the class has to be registered.

[System.Classes.GetClass](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.Classes.GetClass)

Answer (score 1):

For the specific scenario in the question body the answer by Andreas Rejbrand (with assistance from hvd) is a good one. However, for the broader problem implied by the question title - how to I convert a string containing a class name to a class reference? - you can utilise extended RTTI in a new(ish) version of Delphi:

```
unit ClassLookupUtils;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Generics.Collections, System.Rtti;

type
  RttiClassLookup = record
  strict private
    class var FMap: TDictionary<string, TClass>;
    class destructor Destroy;
  public
    class function Find(const ClassName: string): TClass; static;
  end;

implementation

class destructor RttiClassLookup.Destroy;
begin
  FMap.Free;
end;

class function RttiClassLookup.Find(const ClassName: string): TClass;
var
  RttiType: TRttiType;
  RttiContext: TRttiContext;
begin
  if FMap = nil then
  begin
    FMap := TDictionary<string, TClass>.Create;
    for RttiType in RttiContext.GetTypes do
      if RttiType is TRttiInstanceType then
        FMap.AddOrSetValue(RttiType.Name.ToLowerInvariant, (RttiType as TRttiInstanceType).MetaclassType);
  end;
  if not FMap.TryGetValue(ClassName.ToLowerInvariant, Result) then
    Result := nil;
end;

end.
```

In use:

```
var
  MyStr: string;
  MyStrClass: TClass;
begin
  //...
  MyStrClass := RttiClassLookup.Find(MyStr);
  if MyStrClass <> nil then
    for I := 0 to Page.ControlCount - 1 do
      if Page.Controls[I].InheritsFrom(MyStrClass) then
      begin
        //...
      end;
```

The background here is that `SomeObj is SomeClass` is implemented as `(SomeObj <> nil) and SomeObj.InheritsFrom(SomeClass)`.

Comment: RTTI makes you create your own dictionary? Ouch. Great code and I think this does indeed answer the original question.

Comment: TRttiContext has a FindType method, however that requires a fully qualified name passed to it (e.g. 'Vcl.StdCtrls.TGroupBox') and the OP wished to use an unqualified name.

Answer (score 0):

You have a good answer from @UweRaabe using`RTTI`to get`ClassName`.

A simple (and not very robust) hack without using RTTI would be to use the TComponent.Name property, which is a string, like this - without the `is` operator:

```
 If (pos('GroupBox', page.Controls[0].name)>0 ) then ...
```

By default, a control gets the same name as the instance variable, so `GroupBox1.name='GroupBox1`'. You can either change your database entries to use the substr 'groupbox' or extract 'groupbox' from the type name string in your database.

That being said, if you've inherited this design approach of persisting type names as strings in a database and then using them at runtime to check the types of different components, then you're stuck with it, and so be it. But Delphi is a strongly typed, compiled language, so persisting type names as strings in a database and reading them at runtime and decoding them into Delphi types just doesn't "smell right" IMO. I would re-think this design if possible. Consider doing it all in Delphi using `classOf` type, enumerations, etc.